# spring-boot without template engine

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring-Boot app that is apparently way out of the norm.  It's Spring-MVC, but I don't want to use velocity,thymeleaf or anything.  Ideally I would just use HTML.  Then I use jQuery to make my AJAX calls to my REST services, and then fill in the pages with the returned JSON.  The only way I can mostly get this to work is to put my html under `/src/resources/templates`, and then have a @Controller for each page.  So I have:

@SpringBootApplication

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        SpringApplication.run( Application.class, args );
    }
}
```

and my controllers

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getHome() {
        return "index"
}
```

and

```
@Controller
public class AboutController {
    @RequestMapping("/about")
    public String getAbout() {
        return "about"
}
```

I have looked thru the Spring guides and sample projects, but I don't see how to configure this.  I am using the starter projects to get spring-mvc and security, but otherwise I don't see what I need to do this so navigating to :

**localhost/home**   or **localhost/about**  or **localhost/customer**

Or, is it necessary to have a @Controller for each page?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to use static resources like HTML and JavaScript you can place them into a subfolder of `/src/main/resources` named `/public`, `/static` or `/resources`. For example a file located at `/src/main/resources/public/dummy/index.html` will a accessible via `http://localhost/dummy/index.html`. You won't need a Controller for this.

See also the [Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content).

Comment: Thank you @schlauergerd -Is there anyway to not require the html extension on the url?  Ideally, typing **localhost/office"** would work, but right now I have to append the ".html"  I have **spring.view.prefix=public** and **spring.view.suffix=html** in my application.properties now.