# How to build SPA Spring applications without template engines

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, frontend, single-page-application, backend

For the sake of curiosity trying to build an SPA react spring boot application omitting template engines such as jsp or thymeleaf since it's worth decoupling frontend and backend at least in some cases as far as I understand. Managed to write controllers returning raw json and failed to add controllers returning html template with react script like I succeded to do when thymeleaf was included in dependencies and all html/js/css files were in resources folder. Should I run additional node server returning text/html? Can you give me some sample projects.
Basically I want an app with navbar with links /index /something1 /something2 etc and kinda separate SPA with common html headers footers.

Comment: btw i get application/json content type when i curl this url
https://swapi.co/api/people/1/
But when I open it in browser I see rendered html page and not raw json. How is it possible to do?

Comment: If you can skip server-side rendering then it should be simple. Your backend would be reduced to a JSON-feeder and authentication management through ajax communication.

Comment: @Kunukn I can use ajax to update page. But how to show something besides raw json if all my controllers return only json? Where should i specify which view is displayed on certain url?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a controller serving your frontend, no need for a node server, unless you need server side rendering.

Sample tutorial : https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/

Comment: Thymeleaf template engine is used to render index html page. So I have no other choice? A bunch of controllers returning raw json and a bunch returning html template with jsp/thymeleaf?

Comment: No, thymeleaf is useless here, you can skip it.

Comment: Failed to return view without thymeleaf. And also i have to keep all html css js files in resource folder?

Comment: By default, static resources are served from `/static` folder [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)

Comment: I too found the inclusion of Thymeleaf in that example bizzare.   Did you find the solution to make the view render without it?

Comment: Have you tried static folder without any controller ? [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634865/spring-boot-without-template-engine)